# jquery fading other list items on hover and then keeping item at 100% opacity when clicked

Tags: jquery, click, fade

I'm working on a site where a list of items are 100% opacity and once an item is hovered, all other items reduce to 30% opacity. I this working correctly using the code below. Now what I need is for the item that is clicked on to remain at 100% opacity and removing the fade from the other items. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
$(function() {
$("#input_1_8>li").hover( 
function() {}, 
function() {     
$('#input_1_8>li').fadeTo(0.1, 1.0); 
});

$("#input_1_8>li").hoverIntent(
function(){
$(this).attr('class', 'current'); // Add class .current
$(this).siblings().fadeTo(0.1, 0.3); // Fade other items to 30%
$(this).fadeTo(0.1, 1.0); // Fade current to 100%
}, 
function(){            
$(this).removeClass("current"); // Remove class .current
$(this).fadeTo(0.1, 1.0); // This should set the other's opacity back to 100% on mouseout   
}
); 
$("#input_1_8>li").on('click', function(){
$("#input_1_8>li").unbind("mouseenter").
               unbind("mouseleave");
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$("#sites>li").on('click', function(){
    $("#sites>li").unbind("mouseenter").
                   unbind("mouseleave");
});
```

Comment: Not sure if I put this in the right spot. It is resetting all list items to 100% opacity when clicked.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? "the item that is clicked on to remain at 100% opacity and removing the fade from the other items"

Comment: No, I'm sorry I didn't word that right. I want the item to remain 100% and the other items to remain faded to 30%. So the hover will not effect them anymore.

Comment: I edited my question to match how I have the code currently. Still not working, but possibly because I don't have it right.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's working almost right. The only thing else I would like it to do is not have a hover effect once a list item is clicked. So that the clicked item doesn't fade when the other items are hovered. Thanks for your help.